# style objects with a specific key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following data structure:

```
this.state = {
            active_menu: 2018,
            info: [
                {
                    key: 11,
                    title: 'A',
                    opened: false,
                    content: []
                }, {
                    key: 10,
                    title: 'B',
                    opened: false,
                    content: []
                }, {
                    key: 9,
                    title: 'C',
                    opened: false,
                    content: []
                },
                {
                    key: 1,
                    title: 'D',
                    opened: false,
                    content: []
                }],
            display: true
}
```

Tell me, please, how is it possible with the value of `display:false` to remove (perhaps it can assign style display:none) elements with keys `11`, `10` and `9`? At `display:true` elements `11`, `10` and `9`should be visible, and the element with key `1` is hidden.

Honestly I sit for the third day and can not decide. I ask for your help and would be grateful for any help...

Comment: *"...with keys 11, 10 and 9?"* What makes them special, vs. `key: 1`? I mean, how is the code supposed to know?

Comment: Are you asking how to change the objects in the `info` array, or how to change how you **render** them? (If the latter, please show a [mcve] of your rendering code, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets [the `[<>]` toolbar button]. Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).)

Comment: Almost nothing ... I think im just need to cycle through the keys, but I don’t know how

Comment: Yes, i asking how to change the objects in the array

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, i asking how to change the objects in the array

Since you're not allowed to modify state directly, you create a copy of `info` and its objects:

```
this.setState(({display, info}) => ({
    info: info.map(entry => {
        const {key} = entry;
        const newEntry = {...entry};
        if (!display && (key == 11 || key == 10 || key == 9)) {
            newEntry.display = "none";
        }
        return newEntry;
    })
}));
```

Or if it's okay to have a `display` property with the value `undefined` when it isn't `"none"`:

```
this.setState(({display, info}) => ({
    info: info.map(entry => ({
        ...entry,
        display: !display && (entry.key == 11 || entry.key == 10 || entry.key == 9) ? "none" : undefined
    }))
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use the following code:

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
    return {
        ...prevState,
        display: false,
        info: prevState.info.map(i => {
            if(i.key ===9 || i.key === 10 || i.key === 11) return {...i, display: 'none' }
            else return i
        })
    }
})
```

and something similar for the **true** case.
so what's going on in this code?
First, we use the setState's function argument instead of object one, because we need component's previous state in order to create the new one.
Next, we map over the prevState's info and try to create the new state based on that.
We do this by checking each item's key to see if it is equal to 9, 10 or 11 and if so, returning the modified object, elsewhere, we return the original item without changing it.

But I think your state structure is bad for this use case. so I suggest this one instead:

```
state = {
    active_menu: 2018,
    info: {
        11: {
            title: 'A',
            opened: false,
            content: []
        },
        ....
    }
}
```

And the following code for updating state:

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
    return {
        ...prevState,
        display: false,
        info: {
            ...prevState.info,
            11: {
                ...prevState.info[11],
                display: 'none'
            },
            ...
        }
    }
})
```

And the following one for mapping over the info items:

```
Object.keys(this.state.info).map(infoKey => {
    let info = this.state.info[infoKey];
    // Do whatever you want with info and return the component you want to render
})
```